# Swing Laf Change Issues While Restarting App

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, restart, look-and-feel

I have the following restart method, which is working:

```
public static void restart(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> jvmArgs = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
    // Java
    commands.add(System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java");
    // Jvm arguments
    for (String jvmArg : jvmArgs) {
        commands.add(jvmArg);
    }
    // Classpath
    commands.add("-cp");
    commands.add(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getClassPath());
    // Class to be executed
    commands.add(BaseUI.class.getName());
    // Command line arguments
    File workingDir = null; // Null working dir means that the child uses the same working directory
    String[] env = null; // Null env means that the child uses the same environment
    String[] commandArray = new String[commands.size()];
    commandArray = commands.toArray(commandArray);
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArray, env, workingDir);
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to put the Look And Feel configuration on the main method of my main application but, while restarting, the execution does not enter in that part of the code. So, obviously, the Look and Feel is not changed at all.
Is there any workaround to solve this?

Comment: `I want to put the Look And Feel configuration` - how about creating a method with the LAF code. Then you can invoke that method from the main() or the restart() method.

Comment: Or add `-Dswing.defaultlaf=…` to `commands`.

Comment: Thanks catalina for your answer... But that's the issue... Because I put breakpoints in the main method, but the execution doesnt reach it... So that's weird... The code to change the look adn feel it's easy ! :D